# How to check the media playing status in Gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I am developing one application using Gstreamer, I found some Gstreamer APIs like gst_element_get_state but it seems not appropriate match to check the current media playing status.

I am having device that has two separate app one is for GUI and one is for linux app, using GStreamer I want some API which returns the current status of media weather it is plying or not?

Please give some suggestions how to check this.

Comment: And what makes you think `gst_element_get_state` is not appropriate for this case?